# Is it possible to to solve an equation with both power(?) and exponential terms for $x$?

Tags: exponential-function

If I have an equation of the form $Y=A+x^B+C^x$ is it possible to solve for $x$, where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all rational numbers?

More specifically, is it possible to solve $y=12 + 2x + x^{1.92} + 2^{0.425(x-12)}$ and, if so, how would I do it?

Comment: Your best bet is a numerical solution.

Comment: By numerical solution, do you mean something like plugging in values of X and creating a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no nice formula that expresses $x$ as a function of $y$. For any particular numerical value of $y$ you can use software to find a value of $x$. For examples, if you ask [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%2012%2B2x%2Bx%5E1.92%2B2%5E(0.425(x%E2%88%9212))%3D100) to find $x$ when $y=100$

```
solve  12+2x+x^1.92+2^(0.425(x−12))=100
```

you find out that $y$ is

```
9.0984743836320913466
```

Since your function is increasing, it would be straightforward to write a python program (or a program in any other language) to find values by bisection, or to build a table of values as in a comment. You could even build a table of values in a spreadsheet.